# Node features in dataframe to networkx list of graphs

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, networkx, stellargraph

I have a list of networkx graphs. I have a dataframe with the following info:

```
Out[91]: 
                                                      ln                                                ln2
0      [[67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], ...  {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
1      [[67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], ...  {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
2      [[67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], ...  {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
3      [[67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], ...  {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
4      [[67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], [67, 1], ...  {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
                                                  ...                                                ...
43244  [[71, 1], [73, 1], [79, 1], [80, 1], [80, 1], ...  {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43245  [[71, 1], [73, 1], [79, 1], [80, 1], [80, 1], ...  {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43246  [[71, 1], [73, 1], [79, 1], [80, 1], [80, 1], ...  {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43247  [[71, 1], [73, 1], [79, 1], [80, 1], [80, 1], ...  {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43248  [[71, 1], [73, 1], [79, 1], [80, 1], [82, 1], ...  {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
[43249 rows x 2 columns]
```

Both columns contain the same information, but ones a list and ones a dict. I am trying to iterate over every graph and their respective nodes and adding there associated node feature.

For instance graph[0] has node features in df['ln' or 'ln2'][0]. I have tried:

```
for i in range(len(graphs)):
    for j in range(len(df['ln'][i])):
        for node_data in graphs[i].nodes(data=True):
            node_data['feature'] = df['ln'][i][j]
```

and received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/GeoDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3427, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-75-894a20b5da94>", line 4, in <module>
    node_data['feature'] = df['ln'][i][j]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I have also tried to do it to a single graph:

```
g0.nodes.data(df['ln'][0])
Out[88]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/GeoDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py", line 224, in catch_format_error
    r = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/GeoDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py", line 702, in __call__
    printer.pretty(obj)
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/GeoDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py", line 394, in pretty
    return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/GeoDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py", line 700, in _repr_pprint
    output = repr(obj)
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/GeoDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/classes/reportviews.py", line 302, in __repr__
    return f"{name}({dict(self)}, data={self._data!r})"
  File "/home/anthony/anaconda3/envs/GeoDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/classes/reportviews.py", line 268, in <genexpr>
    (n, dd[data] if data in dd else self._default)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The same result with the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my node IDs prior to assigning the data, therefore it did not recognize the new IDs.